# Bootstrap hidden.bs.collapse event triggers on both collapse('show') and collapse('hide')

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a loading message that I only want to show the animation of hiding within another element that I want to show both hiding and showing. This is for a live search element. And I am stuck using bootstrap 4 btw.
The logic is pretty simple, since the trigger is going to be a search button (but the button has to have `preventDefault` on it since it is natively a submit button.

```js
$(function() {
    const displayResults = (results) => {
      $("#good-results").collapse("show");
      $("#bad-results, #wait-message").collapse("hide");
      $.each(results, (i, result) => {
        let name = $("<p>");
        name.text(result.full_name);
        $("#results-container").append(name);
      });
    };
    const alertNoResults = () => {
      $("#good-results, #wait-message").collapse("hide");
      $("#bad-results").collapse("show");
    };
    const clearResults = () => {
      $("#results-container").empty();
    };
    const hideResultsDiv = () => {
      $("#search-results, #good-results, #bad-result").collapse("hide");
    };
    const showResultsDiv = (results) => {
      $("#good-results, #bad-result").collapse("hide");
      $("#search-results").collapse("show");
    };
    const searchBtn = $("#search-btn");
    searchBtn.on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const search = $("#search");
      clearResults();
      let params = search.val();
      if (params) {
        showResultsDiv();
        // query runs simulated with timeout
        setTimeout(() => {
          let contacts = [{
            full_name: "john doe"
          }, {
            full_name: "jane doe"
          }];
          displayResults(contacts);
        }, 2000);
      } else {
        hideResultsDiv();
      }
    });
    const searchResults = $("#search-results");
    searchResults.collapse({
      toggle: false
    });
    $(document).on("mouseup", function(e) {
      if (!searchResults.is(e.target) && searchResults.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        hideResultsDiv();
      }
    });
    searchResults.on("hidden.bs.collapse", () => {
      $("#wait-message").collapse("show");
    });
  }

);
```

```css
.search-results {
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px #000;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Bootstrap Example For Stack Overflow</h1>
  <div class="card mb-5">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h2 class="card-title">Live Search</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <form class="mt-3" method="post" action="/prefix/controller/action/query">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="input-group">
              <label for="search" class="sr-only">Search</label>
              <input type="search" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search For Contact By Name" />
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-primary input-group-button" type="submit" id="search-btn">Search</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div id="search-results" class="search-results collapse">
        <div id="wait-message" class="collapse show">
          <p class="text-info">Please wait...</p>
        </div>
        <div id="good-results" class="collapse">
          <h4 id="results-count" class="text-success">Found Results</h4>
          <div id="results-container"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="bad-results" class="collapse">
          <p class="text-danger">Nothing Found</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h2>Description</h2>
  <p class="lead">Bootstrap hidden.bs.collapse event triggers on both collapse('show') and collapse('hide')</p>
  <p>I have a loading message that I only want to show the animation of hiding within another element that I want to show both hiding and showing. This is for a live search element. And I am stuck using bootstrap 4 btw. The logic is pretty simple, since
    the trigger is going to be a search button (but the button has to have <code>preventDefault</code> on it since it is natively a submit button.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You are missing `#` here `$("search-results").collapse('show');` . If this doesn't solve your issue please make your code runnable so that we can test it .

Comment: @Swati I have done that now but I couldn't really make it "work" with the embed tool so I made a codepen link.

Comment: Nevermind @Swati I now have the snippet working